# Changing language on login page does not work

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I have a working login system after the user logs in.

```
views.py

def change_language(request):
from django.conf import settings
response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
if request.method == 'POST':
    language = request.POST.get('language')
    if language:
        if language != settings.LANGUAGE_CODE and [lang for lang in settings.LANGUAGES if lang[0] == language]:
            redirect_path = f'/{language}/'
        elif language == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE:
            redirect_path = '/'
        else:
            return response
        from django.utils import translation
        translation.activate(language)
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)
        response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language)
return response
```

Change language button

```
<form action="{% url 'change_language' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <select name="language">
      {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
      {% for language in LANGUAGES %}
      <option value="{{ language.0 }}" {% if language.0 == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
          {{ language.0|language_name_local }} ({{ language.0 }})
      </option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Change language">
```

However on my login page, `/accounts/login/?next=/`, after changing language, instead of getting
`/pl/accounts/login/?next=/`, which would translate the page, I get
`/accounts/login/?next=/pl/`, which translate pages after login for me but that is not what I wanted.

Also, if I try to change my language on my registration page `/accounts/sign_up/` it redirects me again to `/accounts/login/?next=/pl/`

Basically, if the user is not logged in, change_language option redirects him to the login page but there is no `@login_required` decorator so I don't know what is causing it.

How can I make it to just change the language as it does after the login?

Answer (score 0):

I understood my problem. I was just redirecting to home page all the time. `redirect_path = '/'` and the home page had `@login_required` decorator.

In order to redirect to the same page where the user changed language I did this:

Added `<input hidden name="url" value="{{ request.path }}"/>` to my button form

Receive it in my views and crop if it has language (it is quite an ugly way to do this I know):

```
current_site = request.POST.get('url')
if 'pl' in current_site:
    current_site = current_site[3:]
```

And finally change the redirect_path

```
redirect_path = f'/{language}' + current_site
```

So the change_language view looks like this:

```
def change_language(request):
from django.conf import settings
response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
if request.method == 'POST':
    language = request.POST.get('language')
    current_site = request.POST.get('url')
    if 'pl' in current_site:
        current_site = current_site[3:]
    if language:
        if language != settings.LANGUAGE_CODE and [lang for lang in settings.LANGUAGES if lang[0] == language]:
            redirect_path = f'/{language}' + current_site
        elif language == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE:
            redirect_path = current_site
        else:
            return response
        from django.utils import translation
        translation.activate(language)
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)
        response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language)
return response
```

So the problem is resolved but if someone sees anything wrong with my code I would be happy to hear it.